# Twilio Error : The From phone number +1******** is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I am getting this error sometimes even if I received the sms .I have checked sidekiq logs and it shows `"error_class"=>"Twilio::REST::RequestError"`
.I have also checked phone number sms-capablility over twilio account and its status shows it is currently active.

Comment: If you're getting errors but also sending messages then this is probably best dealt with by our support team. You can [use this form to get in contact with Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and let them know what's going on.

Comment: thanks philnash,Its better to change retry option to false for sidekiq .

Comment: Are there logs in your Twilio account that show these failures? I worry that this is a problem that will get hidden if you just turn off retries.

Comment: under my twilio account it only shows the message is delivered with no errors.Its status show it is delivered successfully.Its nice to have your quick response.

Comment: It might be interesting to try to get any errors to log out a bit more information. Such as the code or message from the error, rather than just seeing `Twilio::REST::RequestError`. That would give you a bit more insight into what is happening at least.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error in my Rails project. My problem was a mismatch between the Twilio account SID and auth token and my twilio phone number (I think I was using test credentials with a real Twilio phone number). Once I got these set up correctly in my project, the problem resolved.